# Вписать картинку в блок

Tags: css3

Есть блок заданых размеров и нужно что бы в него вставлялись картинки(именно тегом img) так что бы если например картинка вертикальная она не растягивалась на всю ширину блока, а занимала нужную ей ширину и высоту по блоку. И если нужно например уменьшалась и вписывалась в блок. Это можно сделать средствами css или только с применение js/ Если есть какие то примері или сілки где можно узнать буду благодарен

Comment: Для img пропишите  height:100%; width: auto;  Должно решить вопрос, если я правильно понял

Comment: Картинок в блоке может быть несколько?

Answer (score 1):

Как например:

```js
var imgs = $('.box img');
imgs.each(function(){
    var item = $(this).closest('.box');
    item.css({
        'background-image': 'url(' + $(this).attr('src') + ')', 
        'background-position': 'center',            
        '-webkit-background-size': 'cover',
        'background-size': 'cover', 
    });
    $(this).hide();
});
```

```css
.box {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.js"></script>
  
<div class="box">
  <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1530600130-16d76247813a?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&s=b2eecd049220309cb59506b1393c0211&auto=format&fit=crop&w=600&q=60" alt="">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Все зависит от того вертикальная картинка или горизонтальная. Если горизонтальная, то необходимо: `width: 100%; height: auto`, если вертикальная, то `height: 100%; width: auto`. Вам необходимо только с помощью javascript определить, какого формата картинка и присвоить соответствующие стили

Answer (score 0):

Есть такое свойство, как `object-fit: cover;` оно позволяет `<img>` занимать всё пространство родителя, растягивая изображение без потери пропорций.

```css
.object-fit {
  display: block;
  width: 100px;
  height: 200px;
}

.object-fit img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
}
```

```html
<div class="object-fit">
  <img src="https://bipbap.ru/wp-content/uploads/2017/10/0_8eb56_842bba74_XL-640x400.jpg">
</div>
```

Подробнее - [object-fit - CSS | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/object-fit)